Confusion in proof of Hensel's Lemma in elementary number theory ( Kenneth H. Rosen's Book )
I am reading proof of Hensel's Lemma in the Kenneth H. Rosen's Elementary number theory, Fifth Edition and some confusion arises.

Theorem 4.14. Hensel's Lemma. Suppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and that $k$ is an integer with $k\ge 2$. Suppose further that $r$ is a solution of the congruence $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k-1}}$. Then,

(i) if $f'(r) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then there is a unique integer $t$, $0 \le t < p$, such that $f(r+ tp^{k-1})\equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$, given by $$ t \equiv -\overline{f'(r)}(f(r)/p^{k-1}) \pmod{p},$$ where $\overline{f'(r)}$ is an inverse of $f'(r)$ modulo $p$ ;
(ii) if $f'(r) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and $f(r) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$, then $f(r+tp^{k-1}) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$ for all integers $t$ ;
(iii) if $f'(r) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and $f(r) \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$, then $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$ has no solutions with $x\equiv r \pmod{p^{k-1}}$.

In case (i), we see that a solution to $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k-1}}$ lifts to a unique solution of $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$, and in case (ii), such a solution either lifts to $p$ incongruent solutions modulo $p^{k}$ or to none at all.

Proof. If $\bar{r}$ is a solution of $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$, then it is also a solution of $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k-1}}$. Hence it equals $r+ tp^{k-1}$ for some integer $t$. The proof follows once we have determined the conditions on $t$.
( Next proof is omitted ).
I'am comfused about the bold statement. Is it really true? I don't think that any solution of $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k}}$ needs to always be of the form $r+tp^{k-1}$ for some integer $t$. I think that we are just investigating solution of $f(x) \equiv \pmod{p^{k}}$ among elements of the form $r + t p^{k-1}$. How do you think about this?

You are correct in that there could be multiple solutions mod $p^{k-1}$, and a solution mod $p^k$ could extend any one of those. But it isn't a problem. The bold statement is more motivational than a rigourous claim, and I believe the rest of the proof just shows how to pick $t$ such that $r+tp^{k-1}$ is a root mod $p^k$ under the assumption that $r$ is one mod $p^{k-1}$.

So the statement should be replaced by "of the form $r'+tp^{k-1}$ for some solution $r'$ mod $p^{k-1}$ and some integer $t$".

@FrançoisGatine : Yes. :)
